# retrieving google documents contents into a vb windows form

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to extract the contents of a google drive file. It is a google document file. I have the code to pull the entire document, including metadata, etc. I saw the google api page concerning this: https://developers.google.com/drive/...m_google_drive

I am having trouble being able to parse the body out of what I am getting from my code. Has anyone done this? thanks, Victor.

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("insert google doc url here"), HttpWebRequest)

                Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

                Dim Stream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()

                Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Stream)

                MsgBox(reader.ReadToEnd)
```

Answer (score 0):

[get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) method returns export links. I think you can use this method for retrieving file metadata and export links for retrieving content. You can export file to "plain text" format and RTF format (and many others).

Below a I present example image which contains URL's to file content(from [APIs explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.get)):
[image]

Example links:

```
application/rtf: https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=ID&exportFormat=rtf

text/plain: https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=ID&exportFormat=txt
```